# Swift - How to get the button value, when it is being pressed?

Tags: swift

i want to get button value, when it get pressed.

I've tried this to print a 4*4 Matrix by given code-

```
func creation_of_btn()
{
var x_axis:CGFloat = 50.0
var y_axis:CGFloat = 50.0

for x in 1...4
{
  for y in  1...5
  {
       let btn_creat = UIButton.buttonWithType(UIButtonType.Custom) as UIButton!
       btn_creat.frame = CGRectMake(x_axis, y_axis, 100, 100)
       x_axis += 110.0
       btn_creat.backgroundColor = UIColor .redColor()

       btn_creat.font = UIFont .boldSystemFontOfSize(50)

       var myString = String(self.rand_creation(1, second: 9))
       btn_creat .setTitle(myString, forState: UIControlState.Normal)
       btn_creat.addTarget(self, action: "btnAction:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
       self.view.addSubview(btn_creat)
   }
   
   x_axis = 50.0
   y_axis += 110.0
}
}
```

When button is pressed, the code is -

```
func btnAction (sender:UIButton!)
{
   println("pressed")
}
```

By above code, I'm getting the following output-
[image]

**Now, when i press Button 1, I want to print the button value, which is 1.**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You receive the pressed *UIButton* as `sender` parameter. So you can read the title text of the *UIButton*.

```
println(sender.titleLabel.text)
```

Or if the titleLabel of the button differs from the value, use the attribute `tag`. You can define the tag value in the creation process of the UIButtons.

Answer (score 6):

One way to achieve what you want is to use the `tag` property of `UIButton`.

Add this line to the loop that creates the button:

```
btn_creat.tag = self.rand_creation(1, second: 9)
var myString = String(btn_creat.tag)
```

Now that your tag is set to the button's number, you can print it in the `btnAction:` code:

```
println(sender.tag)
```

Answer (score 3):

You already setup title, so just get it back.

```
func btnAction(sender: UIButton) {
    println(sender.currentTitle!)
}
```